# Legend of controlgroups vertically centered but only if created statically

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I create a controlgroup statically, its legend is perfectly vertically arranged. But when another controlgroup is created dynamically, its legend is aligned at the top.

Please see fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/H5mMu/8/

```
<div id="term_grp" data-role="fieldcontain"><a>Semester:</a>
        <fieldset id="term_fields" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input type="radio" name="term" id="ss"/><label for="ss">Sommersemester</label>
            <input type="radio" name="term" id="ws" checked="checked"/>    <label for="ws">Wintersemester</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<div id="datum_grp" data-role="fieldcontain" data-type="horizontal"><a class="grpLegend">Datum:</a>
<fieldset id="datum_1_fields" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="forceinline"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="datum_2_fields" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="forceinline"></fieldset>
</div>
 <div id="zeit_grp" data-role="fieldcontain"><a class="grpLegend">Stunden:</a>
 <fieldset id="zeit_1_fields" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="forceinline"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="zeit_2_fields" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="forceinline"></fieldset>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#datum_1_fields .ui-controlgroup-controls').find('div').first().remove();
$('#datum_2_fields .ui-controlgroup-controls').find('div').first().remove();
$('#zeit_1_fields .ui-controlgroup-controls').find('div').first().remove();
$('#zeit_2_fields .ui-controlgroup-controls').find('div').first().remove();
```

Comment: great !! If you have more than two datum_fields or zeit_feilds try to use any loop to remove the unwanted div instead of writing code for every feild.

Comment: Cool, in jsFiddle it now works as expected. Unfirtunately, not in my project. I need to find out what's the difference. But anayway, thanks for pointing me into the right direction!